# How do you position divs on a line with space in the middle, without fixing the width of the container?

Tags: css

Warning, possible variation of a FAQ coming up.

I have the following markup :

```
 <html>
 <body>
  <div id="top">Top</div>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="A">A</div>
   <div id="B">B</div>
   <div id="C">C</div>
  <div id="D">D</div>
  </div>
 <div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to have it display this :

```
Top
AB  (lots of space) CD
Bottom
```

I can *not* set the width of the container div (or the size of pretty much anything, for that matter).

As you might have guess, I have not been able to display this correctly. The closest I've got is this :

```
#container {
 margin-right : auto;
 margin-left :auto;
 border : 1px solid red;
}

#A,#B {
  float : left;
}

#C,#D {
 float : right;
}  

#bottom {
 clear : both;
}
```

Which, unsurprisingly, gives the following result :

```
Top
AB (lots of space) DC
Bottom
```

The elements that are told to float to the right float to the right, so the order is reversed, I get that. Is there however a way to obtain my expected result ?

If possible, I would like to stay clear of :

- fixing the width of container (fixing the width of one of the C/D boxes might be allowed)
- wrapping A-B and C-D in their own container boxes (I guess that would work but I don't understand why it would be required, and I've made a vow not to trust my instinct on CSS any more).
- changing the order of C & D in my markup (I though of that, but is it really mandatory to change the markup, in a counter-intuitive way just to display it properly ? How about 'markup is for meaning, CSS is for styling' ?)

As always when I try to style something, I feel like a complete dumbass, so if it's impossible, or you have an explanation, please do not hesitate to explain it to me like I'm a 6 year old child that does not understand CSS at all. (I'm pretty much a 30year old child that does not understand CSS at all.)

---

[BEGIN_RANT]

EDIT : Thanks for all answers. Apparently, the first responses are directed towards "it's impossible". If so, I'm interested into any insight into what I'm missing in the Boxing model, the CSS rules, the theory, the practice or *anything* that could explain to me why such a seemingly trivial thing is impossible.

I fell pretty much like I asked you "I have this variable, and I want to put 10 inside", and every one answers it's not possible.

Is there a "Learn CSS the Hard Way" over there ? A "Tao of CSS" ? A "principle and practice of putting two freaking boxes next to each other in the right order" ?

[END_RANT]

Comment: Assuming you want C&D to appear at the far RHS and to use the full width of the screen, imo the "best" answer is to modify the order of C&D - Any other solution will involve setting a fixed size somewhere, which will result in a solution that is less flexible.

Comment: So you want the space between them to be fluid. How about the widths of the A,B,C,D ? are those fixed ?

Comment: @Gaby : I used text here to simplify ; in my real life example it would be a div with an image and a button. So in general, no, I don't know the exact size of A,B,C,D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to keep the order of C and D, and not want to use set width, then wrapping A-B and C-D is a necessary evil.

**html:**

```
<div id="top">Top</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="AB-wrapper">
        <div id="A">A</div>
        <div id="B">B</div>
    </div>
    <div id="CD-wrapper">
        <div id="C">C</div>
        <div id="D">D</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
```

**css:**

```
#container {
    margin-right : auto;
    margin-left :auto;
    border : 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden; /*added so the border actually wraps the divs*/
}

#AB-wrapper {
    float: left;
}
#CD-wrapper {
    float: right;   
}

#A, #B, #C, #D {
    float: left;   
}

#bottom {
    clear : both;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VEuxj/

---

But if you're really insistent on **not changing the html**,
here's an updated CSS:

```
#container {
    margin-right : auto;
    margin-left :auto;
    border : 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden; /*added so the border actually wraps the divs*/
}

#A, #B {
    float: left;   
}

#C, #D {
    float: right;   
}

#C {
   width: 22px;
   margin-left: -22px; 
}

#bottom {
    clear : both;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8wwq2/

Comment: Thanks, I did not new this jsfiddle thing. Still can't believe my problem is unsolvable without changing the markup. Come'on, this must be a bad dream, someone's going to pinch me and I'll wake up in a world where CSS makes sense ;) ...

Answer (score 0):

Keep what you have and change your html to the following

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="top">Top</div>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="A">A</div>
   <div id="B">B</div>
   <div id="D">D</div>
   <div id="C">C</div>
  </div>
 <div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will put c before d visually.

Comment: I think the OP is aware of this, as he already pointed out that "The elements that are told to float to the right float to the right, so the order is reversed, I get that. "  I believe the OP wants to do this purely in CSS

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is also one of the "cheats" I would like to avoid (I clarified the question). Supposedly I should'nt have to change the markup to obtain my result ? Otherwise, a <table> will do ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use another div `#separator` in between AB and CD.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="top">Top</div>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="A">A</div>
   <div id="B">B</div>
   <div id="separator">&nbsp;</div>
   <div id="C">C</div>
   <div id="D">D</div>
  </div>
 <div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css like

```
#container {
 margin-right : auto;
 margin-left :auto;
 border : 1px solid red;
}

#A,#B,#C,#D {
  float : left;
}

#separator {
 float : left;
 width:100px;
}  

#bottom {
 clear : both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ; however this pretty much means both "changing the markup" and "setting the width" of stuff... which is what I'm trying *not* to do ...

Comment: In that case. Keep your html markup the same as before. Change the css:

#C,#D {float:left;}

#C {margin-left:25px;}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by wrapping just the right group of elements (C and D)

```
<div id="top">Top</div>
<div id="container">
        <div id="A">A</div>
        <div id="B">B</div>
    <div id="rightgroup">
        <div id="C">C</div>
        <div id="D">D</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
```

and alter your css to

```
#A,#B,#C,#D {
  float : left;
}

#rightgroup {
 float : right;
}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/WTwZH/1/

---

Alternatively, if the A,B,C,D element have fixed size then you can use relative/absolute positioning to achieve the effect you want..